# Laravel axios listing relational data

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-8

I am making an axios request to the address I specified below with Laravel.
I want the incoming data to come as follows.
I want to list the data with `language` `en` from the `categories` table and list the data matching (language) with the `category_id` in the `pages` table, but I was not successful. Where am I doing wrong?

http://localhost:3000/categories?lang=en

**Mysql Table & Model**

```
Mysql Table

SELECT * FROM `categories`
id
title
slug
language

Model
class Category extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function pages(): \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Page::class, 'category_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

**Mysql Table & Model**

```
Mysql Table

SELECT * FROM `pages`
id
title
slug
content
category_id
language

Model
class Page extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
}
```

**Routing**

```
Route::prefix('categories')->group(function () {
    Route::get('', [CategoryController::class, 'index']);
});
```

**CategoryController**

```
public function index()
    {
       return $category = Category::where('language', 'en')->with('pages')->get();
    }
```

**output**

```
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "corporate",
        "slug": "corporate",
        "seo": null,
        "order": "0",
        "status": "1",
        "language": "en",
        "created_at": "2022-04-04T13:31:27.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2022-04-04T13:31:27.000000Z",
        "pages": null
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "title": "new category",
        "slug": "new -category",
        "seo": null,
        "order": "0",
        "status": "1",
        "language": "en",
        "created_at": "2022-04-08T12:23:57.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2022-04-08T12:23:57.000000Z",
        "pages": null
    }
]
```

**what i want**

```
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "corporate",
        "slug": "corporate",
        "seo": null,
        "order": "0",
        "status": "1",
        "language": "en",
        "created_at": "2022-04-04T13:31:27.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2022-04-04T13:31:27.000000Z",
        "pages": null,
        "children": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "title": "hello word",
                "slug": "hello-word",
                "content": "",
                "category_id": "2",
                "language": "en"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "title": "new category",
        "slug": "new -category",
        "seo": null,
        "order": "0",
        "status": "1",
        "language": "en",
        "created_at": "2022-04-08T12:23:57.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2022-04-08T12:23:57.000000Z",
        "pages": null,
        "children:": []
    }
]
```

Comment: Where is `$data` first declared? I might be missing something in new developments in Laravel - is the `$data` instance variable available to you?

Comment: i didn't understand what you mean

Comment: If I am not mistaken, you haven't declared your `$data` variable. You can't assign to it without having delcared it first e.g. `$data = [];` but maybe this is done somewhere else in your code, or possibly by the Laravel controller... though I'm not sure about this.

Do you not get any error output?

Comment: the problem is not there, at the moment I couldn't establish the relationship and write the query

Comment: So do you have any error output at all? Have you even checked if you can query it via the console? Before going ahead and connecting up the third step of integration with frontend code?

Comment: I edited the query and write the output above,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243715/discussion-between-liza-and-jonathan).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a page has one category, and a category has many pages, your relationship seems to be incorrect.

Change it to:

```
class Category extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function pages(): \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\hasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Page::class, 'category_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

and in page model, add:

```
class Page extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function category(): \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'id', 'category_id');
    }
}
```

then you should be able to use `->with('pages')` on your `Category` model

Comment: Good spot. The relation was the wrong way around! The Page model should definitely have the inverse relationship defined too. Worth noting the inverse relation isn't explicitly required for `Category::where(x)->with('pages')` to work, but is a good practise to follow through all the relationship definitions the app is capable of providing

Comment: well this way but how should my routing be?

Comment: @Liza you should still be able to use `index()` the way you've provided it above, if it is not working could you specify why?